# Is this supposed to be referencing part of a Haiku or something?

Tags: meaning

This is a normally spoken quote in an interview, but to me it sounds poetic. I'm not sure if this is quoting a Haiku, or supposed to be making reference to something hidden deep in Japanese culture or what.

Too above my current understanding.

> 「自分のやりたいこと、好きなこと、それをそのままぶつけるという、そういうスタイルですね 。」
> 「基本的に、彼自身がいろんなことを経験してる中から集まってきて、凝縮していくっていう、そんな感じですね 。」

Here's google translate doing it's job:

> *"It's a style of what you want to do, what you like, and hitting it as it is."
> "Basically, he gathers from the experience of various things and condenses. is not it ."*

Comment: What part specifically are you referring to as "poetic" or "haiku-ish"?

Comment: The 1st sentence where he is speaking in a manner that seems to be indirect. But I'm pretty sure he's talking about Gunpei Yokoi, without making reference to him or saying his name.

Comment: Anything haiku-ish would need to have the 5-7-5 mora structure, which is completely missing from these quotes.  It's also not clear what you mean by _"[t]his is normally spoken quote in an interview"_ -- do you mean that this same pair of phrases shows up in multiple other places, used by multiple speakers?

Comment: I guess you are right in that "normally spoken quote" does have many different nuances. I myself just forgot what that meant exactly from when I posted this 2 hours ago. And I think your assessment of the 'haiku' thing is spot on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not well-organized sentences since they are from an interview, and the second sentence is a bit "abstract", but they have nothing to do with poetry, haiku, famous saying or anything specific to the Japanese culture.

These sentence are saying that his great ideas come directly from a "condensed mishmash" of what he wants to do, what he likes and what he has experienced. That is, his ideas are not the product of logical deep thinking, but they come rather intuitively from him.